# Extracting String in R

Tags: r, strsplit

I am wanting to extract strings from elements in a data frame. Having gone through numerous previous questions, I am still unable to understand what to do! This is what I have tried to do so far:

```
unlist(strsplit(pcode2$Postcode,"'"))
```

I get the following error:

> Error in strsplit(pcode2$Postcode, "'") : non-character argument

which I understand because I am trying to reference the data rather than putting the text in the code itself. I have 16,000 cases in a dataframe so also not sure how to vectorise the operation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Data:

```
    Postcode    Locality    State   Latitude    Longitude
1   ('200', Australian National University  ACT -35.280,    149.120),
2   ('221', Barton  ACT -35.200,    149.100),
3   ('3030',    Werribee    VIC -12.800,    130.960),
4   ('3030',    Point Cook  VIC -12.800,    130.960),
```

I want to get rid of the commas and braces etc so that I am left with the numeric part of Column 1 which is Postcode, numeric part of `Latitude and`Longitude. This is how the I am hoping the final result will look like:

```
    Postcode    Locality    State   Latitude    Longitude
1   200 Australian National University  ACT -35.280 149.120
2   221 Barton  ACT -35.200 149.100
3   3030    Werribee    VIC -12.800 130.960
4   3030    Point Cook  VIC -12.800 130.960
```

Lastly, I would also like to understand how to nicely format the data in the questions.

Comment: You can find out how to format code by clicking the question mark on the right side of the edit box ("Markdown Editing Help").

Comment: can you post the results of `dput(head(pcode2))`

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do might be to just read in the original data using `read.csv()`. You might have to do something about the parentheses and trailing comma.

Comment: @ Chris, the result of dput(head(pcode2)) is lot of data, couple of screens fly off in doing so. Should I "factor" the  columns first as pcode2 is a small subset of the data?

Comment: @ Tim - The original data is in the format as per below: INSERT INTO postcodes_geo (postcode, suburb, state, latitude, longitude) VALUES
, ('200', 'Australian National University', 'ACT', -35.280, 149.120),
, ('221', 'Barton', 'ACT', -35.200, 149.100),

Comment: You could just show us `dput(head(pcode2$Postcode)))`.  But my guess is that you **don't actually have a column called Postcode**;, i.e. your column headers are messed up; `strsplit(NULL,"'")` gives the same error message.

Comment: I guess this is what you are wanting to see:                                           class = "factor")), .Names = c("Postcode", 
"Locality", "State", "Latitude", "Longitude"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I was looking for the values, not the structure (which is above what you selected in your copy/paste). Based on the data you posted, there should not be many screens of data going by, unless you did not type `head` in the call

Comment: Postcode                       Locality State Latitude Longitude
1  ('200', Australian National University   ACT -35.280, 149.120),
2  ('221',                         Barton   ACT -35.200, 149.100),
3  ('800',                         Darwin    NT -12.800, 130.960),
4  ('801',                         Darwin    NT -12.800, 130.960),
5  ('804',                          Parap    NT -12.430, 130.840),
6  ('810',                          Alawa    NT -12.380, 130.880),